# Arquillian Persistence extension with mysql

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, dbunit

I'm trying to create an integration test using arquillian cube, arquillina APE e docker. 
I manage to start the container and to migrate the schema with flyway.
Now i have a problemi with dbunit.
Whent i try to populate the db with a dataset specified in the resource i have the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: films.TITLE -  (Non-uppercase input column: title) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
at org.arquillian.ape.rdbms.dbunit.DbUnitPopulatorService.lambda$execute$1(DbUnitPopulatorService.java:74)
at org.arquillian.ape.rdbms.dbunit.DbUnitPopulatorService.lambda$executeDataSetOperation$3(DbUnitPopulatorService.java:85)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.arquillian.ape.rdbms.dbunit.DbUnitPopulatorService.executeDataSetOperation(DbUnitPopulatorService.java:85)
at org.arquillian.ape.rdbms.dbunit.DbUnitPopulatorService.execute(DbUnitPopulatorService.java:70)
at org.arquillian.ape.rdbms.core.RdbmsPopulatorConfigurator.execute(RdbmsPopulatorConfigurator.java:118)
at it.advansys.gestionalebdf.server.controller.address.customer.FilmLibraryTest.should_find_all_hollywood_films(FilmLibraryTest.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.arquillian.ape.junit.rule.ArquillianPersistenceRule$1.evaluate(ArquillianPersistenceRule.java:67)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.arquillian.cube.docker.junit.rule.ContainerDslRule$2.evaluate(ContainerDslRule.java:200)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: films.TITLE -  (Non-uppercase input column: title) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:117)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractOperation.getOperationMetaData(AbstractOperation.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:150)
    at org.arquillian.ape.rdbms.dbunit.DbUnitPopulatorService.lambda$execute$1(DbUnitPopulatorService.java:72)
    ... 40 more

here is the code i used

```
@Flyway
@ArquillianResource
RdbmsPopulator flywayRdbmsPopulator;

@DbUnit
@ArquillianResource
RdbmsPopulator dbUnitRdbmsPopulator;

@Test
public void should_find_all_hollywood_films() {

    String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&tinyInt1isBit=false";

    String format = String.format(mysqlUrl, mysql.getIpAddress(), mysql.getBindPort(PORT), DB);
    final URI jdbcUri = URI.create(format);

    flywayRdbmsPopulator
            .forUri(jdbcUri)
            .withDriver(Driver.class)
            .withUsername(USERNAME)
            .withPassword(PASSWORD)
            .usingDataSet("src/test/resources/db/migration")
            .execute();

    dbUnitRdbmsPopulator.forUri(jdbcUri)
            .withDriver(Driver.class)
            .withUsername(USERNAME)
            .withPassword(PASSWORD)
            .usingDataSet("hollywoodfilms.yml")
            .withOptions(options()
                    .schema("hollywood")
                    .build())
            .execute();

    final Table table = new Table(new Source(jdbcUri.toString() + "?currentSchema=hollywood", USERNAME, PASSWORD),
            "films");
    assertThat(table).column("title")
            .value().isEqualTo("Trolls");

    flywayRdbmsPopulator
            .forUri(jdbcUri)
            .withDriver(Driver.class)
            .withUsername(USERNAME)
            .withPassword(PASSWORD)
            .usingDataSet("src/test/resources/db/migration")
            .clean();

}
```

and this is the yml i used to populate the dd:

```
films:
  - title: Trolls
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your `arquillian.xml` too? Important bit here is this part of the error "Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive"

Comment: i don't use any arquillian.xml. i follow a tutorial and i didn't find any xml. Probably i missed this file. where have i to put it and where can i find the format to use?

Comment: We created issue for this and will provide this feature pretty soon https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-2116

Comment: We have just released 2.0.0-alpha.4 version - give it a spin and let us know if that solves your problem.